# How to continue doing research

Tags: research-process, thesis, computer-science, independent-researcher, bachelor

At present I write my bachelor's thesis in the field of computer science and I really enjoy it. I would like to continue doing research after I'll have finished my thesis. Is there any way to do that in parallel to my master programme? I think there are two ways in general and would like to hear what your opinion is.

#### Ask a professor

Are professors interested in supervising a student having only a bachelor's degree? Of course I would work free of charge because I would profit from a better CV and maybe good chances of a career at that chair. I should also mention that the chair I'm writing at is very practically oriented and my professor is a really student-friendly person. They work on real projects and implement algorithms rather than design them. I think that they could benefit from me beacuse I'm a very talented guy with years of experience.

#### Do research on my own

I could also try to publish papers on my own. But this way is somewhat to hard I think because I would have no reviewers nor topics to write about.
I can also imagine to write scientific blog posts; probably nobody will read them but that would be okay since I could reference them in my future applications.

So do you guys have any tipps for me how to accomplish it?

Comment: I'm confused - if you are enrolled in a masters degree, why not do research as part of your masters (e.g. a masters thesis)?

Comment: Unfortunately, a master thesis is only possible at the end of your studies.

Comment: Then talk to the faculty in your masters program, and ask them whether (and how) you can do research.  Their advice is probably better for your situation than our generic advice.

Comment: Look for research opportunities.  My university for example have summer scholarships that are only opened for undergraduate students.  Students then continue their summer project as part of their final year thesis.  If they are keen, maybe a PhD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talk to your current professor. If he likes the idea, he might give you the opportunity to use his resources and provide guidance. This could be a preparation to your future master thesis.

If you have less of an idea what you want to do exactly, look out for research assistant/student assistant positions (or ask around if someone needs help), where you could be part of a research project by helping out with simpler (but no less important) tasks. Though I'm not sure this is a thing in computer science.